# How is the Markov Chain generated by the Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm Ergodic?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

I understand that the Markov Chain generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm satisfies the detailed balance condition, thus implying that the chain has a stationary distribution, $\pi(.)$, say.

However, I'm not sure how we can then apply the ergodic theorem to this Markov Chain? The ergodic theorem states that the chain must be positive recurrent, aperiodic and irreducible; but all we know about the Markov Chain generated by the MH algorithm is that it has $\pi(.)$ as its stationary distribution?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Typically we construct the M-H sampler so that the resultant Markov Chain is positive recurrent, irreducible, and aperiodic, the first two of which imply that the MC has a stationary distribution and the last two of which imply that it is ergodic.  The detailed balance condition serves the additional, critical, purpose of ensuring that the steady state distribution is actually what you want it to be (i.e., that $\pi(\dot)$ is not just any steady state dist'n, but the posterior distribution itself.)  There's more to it, of course, but as a comment this will probably suffice.